# Does NodeJS require a multi cores VPS

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, vps, next.js

I want to develop a website with Nuxt.js or Next.js in 1 core CPU 2.4Ghz, 1GB RAM.

Can my website run fast as a start?

How many requests per seconds will be available maybe?

Comment: Really depends on what you're building. It is difficult to estimate without doing memory benchmarking of your application

Comment: an e-commerce website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether a Node application benefits from multiple cores is application dependent.

Generally, if the child process or cluster modules are not involved, 
then there is no need to have multiple cores on your system because Node.js will only use one core as the request handler always runs on the same event loop, which runs on a single thread.

[How to achieve process concurrency and high throughput](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/):
Because JavaScript execution in Node.js is single-threaded, so a good rule of thumb for keeping your Node server speedy: is to avoid blocking the event loop. You can read about this in the official documentation in my reference below.

[Simple Illustration](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/):
Consider a case where each request to a web server takes 50ms to complete and 45ms of that 50ms is database I/O that can be done asynchronously. 
Choosing non-blocking asynchronous operations frees up that 45ms per request to handle other requests. 
This is a significant difference in your application capacity and processing speed just by choosing to use non-blocking methods instead of blocking methods.

**Reference:**

1. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/
2. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/

I hope this helps.